# How do I build a "Advanced Search Options" dropdown with react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to build something pretty much identical to this snippet in react without jquery. This snippet only works with jquery and jquery does not work well with react:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2q81r

The only examples I can find anywhere are option select examples.

When I try the above snippet it doesn't even show the dropdown without jquery.

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Comment: Check out react-bootstrap.  It wraps up bootstrap nicely in react with no dependencies on jQuery.

Comment: I'm making a codepen right now for it, I'll update the question with it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something you could just make yourself and not have to rely on further dependencies.

Have whether it's open or not tied to a local component state variable, and have each input controlled and updating a local state value.

THere re a ton of great UI libraries if you wanna search around for something that might fit your needs - Semantic UI, Material UI, etc.

Or you can follow along a great tutorial - this one seems decent:
https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-custom-dropdown-menu-component-for-react-e94f02ced4a1/